# Source for a Cpp OpenSSL server with errors

Tags: c++, ssl, tcp, openssl

I have a problem with some source code regarding OpenSSL and Cpp.  For some reason it runs fine but doesn't open a socket!  When I try to connect to it using s_client I get 'Connect: No Error".  When I run netstat I get no open port. It should open a port on 12120. I even disabled my firewall temporarly and it didn't help! BTW I'm using Windows 7.  Thanks for your consideration!  My program just says everythings fine and it starts blocking at the second *BIO_do_accept( abio );*

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

int password_callback(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata)
{
    /* For the purposes of this demonstration, the password is "dw" */

    printf("*** Callback function called\n");
    strcpy(buf, "dw");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    BIO *bio, *abio, *out, *sbio;

    int (*callback)(char *, int, int, void *) = &password_callback;

    printf("Secure Programming with the OpenSSL API, Part 4:\n");
    printf("Serving it up in a secure manner\n\n");

    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    ERR_load_SSL_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    printf("Attempting to create SSL context... ");
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_server_method() );
    if(ctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed. Aborting.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nLoading certificates...\n");
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, callback);
    if(!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "certificate.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    if(!SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "private.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Attempting to create BIO object... ");
    bio = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 0);
    if(bio == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed. Aborting.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nAttempting to set up BIO for SSL...\n");
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    abio = BIO_new_accept("12120");
    BIO_set_accept_bios(abio, bio);

    printf("Waiting for incoming connection...\n");

    if(BIO_do_accept(abio) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);    SSL_library_init();
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        BIO_free_all(abio);
        return 0;
    }

    if(BIO_do_accept(abio) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        BIO_free_all(abio);
        return 0;
    }

    out = BIO_pop(abio);

    if(BIO_do_handshake(out) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Handshake failed.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        BIO_free_all(abio);
        return 0;
    }

    BIO_puts(out, "Hello\n");
    BIO_flush(out);

    BIO_free_all(out);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    BIO_free_all(abio);

    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Your program has some printf's. How far do you get ? Please update your post with your program's output, and maybe the client output.

Comment: My program just says everythings fine and it starts blocking at the second *BIO_do_accept( abio );* I'm really stuck here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you expecting here? You should see port 12120 in LISTENING state. Your client should then be able to connect. Your server then does another accept, which will prevent it reading any I/O on the accepted port, and will ultimately block your client too. I don't know why you are doing two accept's in a row but it's your code.

Comment: I call accept twice because it doesn't block until it hits the second accept.  Thanks for your comment but when I run netstat I don't see any port 12120 at all!  Could you take a look at my source again and maybe give me some more insight before I strip all the SSL out of my sockets

Comment: @user1220811 Then the non-blocking first 'accept' is the problem you should be solving. Doing something twice because the first time didn't work and then trying to debug the resulting invalid program isn't a rational strategy.

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenSSL Documentation for BIO_do_accept():

> BIO_do_accept() serves two functions. When it is first called, after
>   the accept BIO has been setup, it will attempt to create the accept
>   socket and bind an address to it. Second and subsequent calls to
>   BIO_do_accept() will await an incoming connection, or request a retry
>   in non-blocking mode.